# Header path during installation VMware

Tags: kernel, vmware

I have installed VMware on Ubuntu 13.10 but when i launch it then a message said that i 
have to specify the path for the linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic.
Now i'm not expert on linux, i give the command "uname -a" here the result:

```
Linux MarioP 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu
```

My knowledge of linux kernel stops here.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the headers installed? Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

If it installs them, try to reinstall VMware again, it should detect the headers automatically.

Comment: they are already installed!