# Searching for a valid kernel header path in Ubuntu 16.04 VMware

Tags: 16.04, vmware, vmware-tools

I'm using a Ubuntu VM. Very recently I upgraded the system from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04. While installing `./vmware-tools.pl`, I get the following line:

```
Searching for a valid kernel header path...
The path "" is not a valid path to the 4.4.0-116-generic kernel headers.
```

I've been looking at two other solutions online [[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444511/header-path-during-installation-vmware) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware)] but none seem to work.

My main goal is to have Copy/Paste enabled from the Host Machine. It did work for Ubuntu 15.04, it is not working now that I upgraded. Changing Settings in the VM does not seem to be enough.

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your problem seems to be that "copy/paste don't work between VMWare host and guest", but you instead are asking about kernel headers.

Comment: Good catch. Any suggestion?